# Using the Worksheet_Change event on a specific sheet only

Tags: excel, vba, events

So I have a dynamically created worksheet (generated by clicking a command button on a separate sheet) and I am trying to get a `Worksheet_Change` event to fire only on a specific range in that worksheet. My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:K10")) Is Nothing Then
        If sh.Name Like "*SP Temp*" Then
            Dim i As Variant, countOfS As Integer
            countOfS = 0
            For Each i In sh.Range("A1:K10")
                If i.Value = "S" Then
                    countOfS = countOfS + 1
                End If
            Next i
            sh.Range("D12").Value = countOfS
            sh.Range("D13").Value = SCount - countOfS
                ' NOTE: SCount is a global variable set in another Sub
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

The intent is to keep a running count of the number of "S" characters entered into cells in the range `A1:K10`. I have tried adding in `Debug.Print` statements after the `If Not Intersect...` statement, but it doesn't seem to fire, despite the values in the target range being altered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What worksheet module is this event handler in? If the sheet is created at run-time then you can't possibly have an event handler procedure _in that worksheet_ at compile-time, so that handler isn't handling change events for the worksheet you mean to work with... Do you have a `WithEvents` object somewhere that you `Set` to a reference to the runtime-spawned worksheet?

Comment: To handle change events for a particular worksheet spawned at run-time, you need a `WithEvents` variable. Alternatively, you can handle `SheetChange` at the workbook level (in `ThisWorkbook`, assuming the sheet gets created in the same workbook that's hosting the code), and then check if the `Sh` parameter is the worksheet you added.

Comment: If you type `? Application.EnableEvents` in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) and hit Enter, what is the result?

Comment: Please show your code of the Button click event

Comment: Inside a worksheet code module you can use `Me` to refer to the sheet itself - do not use `ActiveSheet` -  the danger there is you update the sheet via code while it's not active, and your code ends up running on the wrong sheet.

Comment: What Tim said, plus beware of [implicit ActiveSheet references](https://rubberduckvba.com/inspections/details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference); if the handler is going to be in `ThisWorkbook`, any unqualified `Range` expression is going to be referring to whatever the active sheet is, and you don't want that. In a worksheet module, the implicit qualifier is `Me`.

Comment: The `Worksheet_Change` routine is in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

Comment: It needs to be in a worksheet module, not a workbook module. Otherwise you need the `Workbook_SheetChange` event handler as mentioned by @MathieuGuindon

Comment: Don't _type_ event handler signatures; select an event provider from the top-left dropdown, then pick an event to handle in the top-right dropdown - notice the code pane has two dropdowns at its top? It's these =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A Workbook SheetChange: Count and Write

**`ThisWorkbook` Module**

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Invalidate.
    
    If Not Sh.Name Like "*SP Temp*" Then Exit Sub ' wrong worksheet
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Sh.Range("A1:K10")
    If Intersect(rg, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no intersection
            
    ' Count.
    
    Dim CountOfS As Long: CountOfS = Application.CountIf(rg, "s")
    
    ' Write
    
    ' Disable events to not re-trigger the event while writing
    ' since the same worksheet is being written to.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sh.Range("D12").Value = CountOfS
        Sh.Range("D13").Value = SCount - CountOfS
    Application.EnableEvents = True
            
End Sub
```